# How do I assign a textcolor to a label from an array of colors?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to make a `UILabel` one of five colors

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSString *randomColor = [colorArray objectAtIndex: arc4random() % [colorArray count]];
    colorArray = [[NSArray alloc] init];
    [UIColor redColor], [UIColor blueColor], [UIColor greenColor], [UIColor yellowColor];
    colorLabel.textColor = randomColor;
}
```

How do I set an object from an array as a `UIColor` for the label textColor? Sorry if this has already been answered, I just can't figure out the right way to phrase it to look it up.

Comment: `colorArray` is not set when you use it. You fill it up after trying to use it. And `UIColor`s are not `NSString`s, or vice versa.

Comment: @duci9y Thanks for the quick response. how would I assign a uicolor to a random color from a list of five colors? what kind of array/dictionary would I use?

Comment: randomColor needs to be a UIColor, not a NSString.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this...

```
#define kNumColors    4

- (UIColor *) randomColor
{
  NSInteger colorIndex = arc4random() % kNumColors;
  UIColor *color;

  switch (colorIndex) {
    case 0:
      color = [UIColor blueColor];
      break;
    case 1:
      color = [UIColor redColor];
      break;
    case 2:
      color = [UIColor yellowColor];
      break;
    case 3:
      color = [UIColor greenColor];
      break;
  }
  return color;
}
```

To assign a random color...

```
colorLabel.textColor = [self randomColor];
```